# Typescript definition file d.ts function optional properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function with options. Depending on what option properties exist, different types of results are returned. The function is written in plan JS, i want to give it types using an index.d.ts file.

Here's some example calls and what it returns:

```
func(): Results

func({key: 'str'}): DifferentResults

func({keys: ['a', 'b']}): EvenMoredifferentResults
```

How can I define this in the index.d.ts file? Also `key` and `keys` should be mutually exclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you should be able to do it with the same definitions you'd use for [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

you should be able to write several explicit definitions followed by a universal definition; typescript will choose the most appropriate definition to check in context.

Comment: Yup, you use interfaces to define different option types. Then make a bunch of overloads. nice